# Incomplete Panel Data?

Tags: panel-data

I have a data set where each individual is observed twice (in period 1 and 2) - i.e. for each individual, I observe the dependent variable (y_i) and (various) independent variables in period 1 and 2. However, an independent variable of interest (x_i) is observed only in period 2 (x_i may be different between periods 1 and 2). I would like to measure how y_i varies with x_i. The simplest way is to run an OLS using data for period 2: y_i2 = alpha_0 + alpha_1(x_i) + alpha(other independent variables in period 2). How can I use the panel structure in my data set to reduce omitted variable bias in this regression? Thanks.